# Cannot open directory a second time

Tags: c, directory

I have a problem opening the same directory on second call.
For example i first open folder1/folder2; then if i call the function i'm using on folder1 it says it cannot open it. I though I would close all directories in a path and tried to do it but with no results.
This is my code

```
void scanDir(char *dir, int depth, char type, char *path, long gtsize, int attrib)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;
    char newPath[strlen(path)+strlen(dir)];
    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open directory %s\n because of e", dir);
        exit(10);
        return;
    }
    strcpy(newPath, path);
    strcat(newPath, dir);
    if (type!='f' && testAttrib(attrib, dir))
        printf("%s\n", newPath); 
    strcat(newPath, "/");
    chdir(dir);
    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        stat(entry->d_name,&statbuf);

        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode) && testAttrib(attrib, entry->d_name)) {
            if(!strcmp(".",entry->d_name) || !strcmp("..",entry->d_name))
               continue; // ignore . and ..
            if (depth>1 || depth<=-1)
                scanDir(entry->d_name,depth-1,type,newPath,gtsize,attrib);
        }
        if(S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode) && type!='d' && testAttrib(attrib, entry->d_name)) {
                off_t sizeF = statbuf.st_size;
                char filePath[100];
                strcpy(filePath, newPath);
                strcat(filePath, entry->d_name);
                if(sizeF>=gtsize)
                    printf("%s \n", filePath);
            }
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}
```

Comment: Well, look about the error ? `perror()` for example.

Comment: it joins in the first if and print "Cannot open directory"

Answer (score 2):

```
char newPath[strlen(path)+strlen(dir)];  //WRONG!
```

is certainly wrong. You need to reserve one extra byte for the terminating 0 and you are adding a `/`. So it should be

```
char newPath[strlen(path)+strlen(dir)+2];
```

BTW, consider using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) instead of your `strcat` calls.

I am not sure that calling [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) is a wise idea, and you certainly should check that it went well. See [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html).

Look also into [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).

Comment: It's still too short because he also adds a trailing `/`.

Comment: Then use `errno` and try [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program. Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger `gdb`**

Answer (score 1):

in struct dirent, member d_name contains name without path. This means that parameter passed to the function, opendir(), does not have path to file or directory so that error ENOENT happens.

lets say you have directory /home/usr/folder1/folder2. and you call

`scandir("/home/usr/folder1/", 2, type, ...) // I understood only first two parameters.`

this functions seems to work but when the function calls itself recursively to search /home/usr/folder1/folder2

`if (depth>1 || depth<=-1)
   scanDir(entry->d_name,depth-1,type,newPath,gtsize,attrib);`

the first parameter passed to the scandir this time is "folder2" not "/home/usr/folder1/folder2" so opendir(dir) gives error named ENOENT

and one more thing you should be careful is that readdir() function is not reentrant function so that calling readdir() function may result in not expected error. in your code, it looks like the function gives result as you want. However, I think "how it works" may be different from what you think. if the code becomes complicated, i recommends to use readdir_r() function which is re-entrant version of readdir

according to the man page of readdir:

> On success, readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure.  (This
>          structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to free(3) it.)

after recursively calling scandir() function, in each stack of function, your entry becomes NUll pointer since the structure is statically allocated.

another suggestion for you function is that using nftw() or scandir() functions offered by linux. especially nftw is really powerful and does most of you want.